# Download website content one by one through Async task

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have an application in which I am trying to download an **ArrayList** of **urls** using an Async Task Manager and  and than show the content of per website one by one.I am so confused please help me.I have also tried to use a **for** loop on the execute method but it thorws me an error.

Please let me know what i have to do with the required code.

Thanks.

**Async task**

```
public class DownloadWeb extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        URL myUrl;

        try{

            myUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            //!!!!!!!!! The page will not re direct!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!//


            String redirect = connection.getHeaderField("Location");

            if(redirect != null){

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(redirect).openConnection();

            }


            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){

                stringBuilder.append(line);
                result = stringBuilder.toString();

            }

            return result;




        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }




        return null;
    }
}
```

**The onCreate method**

```
DownloadWeb task = new DownloadWeb();
    try {
        String res = task.execute(arr.get(0)).get();




    }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: [get() "**waits** if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result."](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)

Comment: Do not use .get() on an AsyncTask to begin with. Very bad programming.

Comment: `but it thorws me an error.`. If so then you should of course tell wich error and better yet post the LogCat.

Comment: `show the content of per website one by one`. Show the pages one by one? And when such a page should be changed? Who would trigger the change to a new page and when? There is nothing in your code that shows how you handle the result.

Answer (score 0):

try to execute your async task on Executor

```
asyncTask1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
// asyncTask2 will only be done AFTER asyncTask1 is done
asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

or you can create a custom queue and execute add your asyncTask in there

refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR